# Cannot deserialize JSON with both UTC and non UTC formatted datetimes

Tags: c#, json, datetime, json.net

I am reading in JSON from an external API.  The datetime values are formatted differently for some reason and I cant get it to automatically deserialize into my object using Newtonsoft.Json.

For example, suppose the following is my JSON (the only diff in the two datetime values is the first one ends in 'Z' and the second does not):
string json = "{ \"DateTime1\" : \"20131101T000000Z\", \"DateTime2\" : \"20131101T000000\" }";

Then I need to parse the 2 datetime fields into an object containing DateTime1 and DateTime2 properties like this:

```cs
class Foo
{
    public DateTime DateTime1 { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime2 { get; set; }
}
```

My deserialization code looks like this:

```cs
var format = "yyyyMMddThhmmssZ"; // your datetime format

var dateTimeConverter = new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = format };

JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
serializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local;
serializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
serializerSettings.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset;

string json = "{ \"DateTime1\" : \"20131101T000000Z\", \"DateTime2\" : \"20131101T000000\" }";

try
{
    var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(serializerSettings);
    var o3 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json, dateTimeConverter);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    var x = ex.Message.ToString();
}

return;
```

Running the code above gives me:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your datetime format string for `IsoDateTimeConverter` doesn't look correct, try to update it per following

```cs
var dateTimeConverter = new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "yyyyMMddTHHmmssK" };
```

According to [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings),
`K` format specifier is used for time zone information, there is no `Z` format specifier

Comment: Thanks alot Pavel.  I figured it was something like that but I wasnt sure how to express the 'Z' in the UTC format.  Your answer worked perfectly!